Why does button with onClick lambda recompose twice on every click?
Why does button recompose twice on every click?
Code snippet:
var counter by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
Button(onClick = { counter++ }) {
  Text(text = "I've been clicked $counter times")
}

Observation:
When button is clicked x times, Button is seen to have recomposed 2x times as per layout inspector.


Recompositions happen for Surface in implementation of Button because of elevation change. And it's often more than twice of the clicks. If you hold your finger on Button and release it, you can observe recompositions after you release as well.
Source code of Button for Material library, i only commented elevation to pass it to SideEffect.
@Composable
fun MyButton(
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource? = null,
    elevation: ButtonElevation? = ButtonDefaults.elevation(),
    shape: Shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
    border: BorderStroke? = null,
    colors: ButtonColors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(),
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = ButtonDefaults.ContentPadding,
    content: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit
) {
    @Suppress("NAME_SHADOWING")
    val interactionSource = interactionSource ?: remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
    val contentColor by colors.contentColor(enabled)

    val elevationValue = elevation?.elevation(enabled, interactionSource)?.value ?: 0.dp

    SideEffect {
        println("Recomposing... $elevationValue")
    }

    Surface(
        onClick = onClick,
        modifier = modifier.semantics { role = Role.Button },
        enabled = enabled,
        shape = shape,
        color = colors.backgroundColor(enabled).value,
        contentColor = contentColor.copy(alpha = 1f),
        border = border,
        elevation = elevationValue,
//        elevation = elevation?.elevation(enabled, interactionSource)?.value ?: 0.dp,
        interactionSource = interactionSource
    ) {
        CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides contentColor.alpha) {
            ProvideTextStyle(
                value = MaterialTheme.typography.button
            ) {
                Row(
                    Modifier
                        .defaultMinSize(
                            minWidth = ButtonDefaults.MinWidth,
                            minHeight = ButtonDefaults.MinHeight
                        )
                        .padding(contentPadding),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                    content = content
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

You can observe value changes in SideEffect. If you comment elevation you won't see extra recompositions.
